# For Google Places API, does an Empty result count against your quota?

Tags: google-api, google-places-api

I read through the pricing pages on Google but cannot find if Empty results count against your quota. I have a large dataset (100k records) but know some of the results will be empty due to businesses closing. I want to know if that will affect my total expected quota and therefore price.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related. OP should contact Google about quota related questions with their api.

Comment: Yes empty results do count against quota. But as per the above comment, please contact Maps Billing support on this matter; SO is programming related only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the comments. I have contacted Google and confirmed that empty results do count against the quota. I have suggested that they add this to their online documentation but have added an answer here for anyone else looking for the correct answer until it is available.